# SMTP | Python - Error: authentication failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtp

This is my code:

```
import smtplib

user = 'user@mail.com'
pwd = 'pass'
to = 'to@mail.com'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP(IPadress,25)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
#smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(user, pwd)
header = 'To:' + to + '\n' + 'From: ' + gmail_user + '\n' + 'Subject:testing \n'
print header
msg = header + '\n this is test msg from host \n\n'
smtpserver.sendmail(user, to, msg)
print 'done!'
smtpserver.close()
#
```

Telnet from my host to smtp server works:
telnet IP 25

AUTH LOGIN works, but if I tried send via python I get an error:
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure')

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to login to a gmail account?

Comment: No, this is SMTP in my company.

Comment: Are you sure SMTP protocol is enabled in your company?, SMTP and IMAP are usually not enabled by default in lot of companies for 3rd party clients to access them.

Comment: Ask the local IT administration what the problem is.